# Keeping the volume controls on even with vibrate switch on using MPMoviePlayerViewController like YouTube app does

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

We have an application that uses the MPMoviePlayerViewController and our customer noticed that when the vibrate switch is on, the sound is off and the volume controls are taken away. That seems to be standard behavior.

Now I was expecting the YouTube app to have the same behavior but they don't. When you turn the switch on, you can play YouTube clips and the sound is on and the volume controls are available.

Any idea on how they achieved that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having access to undocumented APIs. The Youtube app on iPhones is an Apple app, meaning they can simply do stuff that you can't.

Comment: hmm I was afraid of that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the audio session category for your app for media playback:

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
```

You can see the various audio categories that are available to your app here: [Audio Session Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html)